# Missing Pentaho MSSQL Native database JDBC driver

Tags: sql-server-2008, jdbc, pentaho

I get the following different error when trying to use MS SQL SERVER native connection with Use Integrated Security box checked.

`Error connecting to database [Kettle_ETL native] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: Error occurred while trying to connect to the database`

Driver class `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` could not be found, make sure the 'MS SQL Server (Native)' driver (jar file) is installed. `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

Using Pentaho Spoon version 5.3 on a Windows 64-bit machine with jre1.8.0_45 installed, I copied the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` (x64 version) and `sqljdbc41.jar` files to the `/data-integration/lib` folder and removed the existing `sqljdbc.jar` file.

Any insight into this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey and welcome to StackOverflow! Recommend you check out the markdown code formatting tools available - these can help make your question easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

The `sqljdbc_auth.dll` should be copied into the `data-integration\libswt\win64` directory.

Even if you are on a 64 bit machine, it's possible that Java/PDI is running in 32 bit, so ot's advisable to also add the 32 bit version of the `sqljdbc_auth.dll` into the `data-integration\libswt\win32` directory.